# I am having trouble with routing , Angular is showing the component before the link is clicked

Tags: angular

I am having trouble with Angular routing. Angular is showing the component before the link is clicked. My Code is Follow:

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    Having trouble with Routing
  </h1>

   <h1>Router Example</h1>

   <a routerLink="/student" routerLinkActive="active">Crisis Center</a>

</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StudentComponent } from './student/student.component';
import { StudentDetailsComponent } from './student-details/student-details.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'student',
    component: StudentComponent
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: The code you provided seems okay. Can you create a stackblitz about your issue?

Comment: @robert i checked this code in stackblitz, the student component is not loaded, and load on click of routerlink but when u refresh the stackblitz browser window the student component is still there even before the click on link, it will however not come if the main browser window is refreshed ! Even i'm curious, although not tested locally, i was trying [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-example-testing)

Comment: @SouravDutta Thank you, just checked. Once you open the link the url is: https://angular-router-example-testing.stackblitz.io then you do the click Student component loads (as expected) but notice that the url has changed to: https://angular-router-example-testing.stackblitz.io/student (student is added at the end) Now if you hit refresh you refreshing the student url that's why it is there.

Comment: @robert yes you are right I had noticed that! So, what could be the reason? is it behaving same locally? or even I'm missing something!

Comment: @SouravDutta This is how routing works. If your url matches any configured route that route will be loaded (no need for explicit clicking). I would say this is the expected correct behavior.

Comment: @robert thanks, I definitely got a little confused after i reloaded the browser window (which actually refreshed stackblitz itself), YES you are right that is how routing works (P.S. i have checked it locally as well to console myself)  :-)

Comment: Thank you all bro.......................